# How to compare different integers with another integer?

Tags: java

```
if ((firstDigit || secondDigit || thirdDigit || fourthDigit || fifthDigit) == 1){
        System.out.println(":::||");
    }
```

Is there a way to do this? `.equals`? `.compareTo` or do I need to do it the slow way by doing each variable? For loop?

Comment: Do you need only 5 digits or any number of digits?

Comment: Do you have an array of these digits ?

Comment: 5 Digits, its for a zip code project.

Comment: @azro  No, I don't have an array, but will that work? Like can i compare it the integer 1 for every digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a helper method:

```
static boolean anyMatch(int find, int... in) {
    for (int n : in)
        if (n == find)
            return true;
    return false;
}
// ...
if (anyMatch(1, firstDigit, secondDigit, ...))
```

Or you can use streams:

```
if (IntStream.of(firstDigit, secondDigit, ...).anyMatch(n -> n == 1))
```

Or you can use `List.contains()`:

```
if (Arrays.asList(firstDigit, secondDigit, ...).contains(1))
```

But the simplest and most efficient option is the one you're avoiding:

```
if ((firstDigit == 1 || secondDigit == 1 || ...)
```

Another point for consideration is whether these should really be distinct variables, instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't legal, and there isn't a short form for or.

```
if (firstDigit == 1 || secondDigit == 1 || thirdDigit == 1  || 
        fourthDigit == 1 || fifthDigit == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

You could also use an `IntStream` (in Java 8+) like

```
if (IntStream.of(firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit, fifthDigit)
        .anyMatch(x -> x == 1)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the second method is likely slower than the first.